# Call to undefined function dl() что может быть не так

Tags: php

В php.ini dl разрешён. Может что ещё в каком файле подредактировать? Web сервер, использую Denwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выдержка из документации http://php.net/manual/ru/function.dl.php

> **Внимание**
>   Эта функция удалена из некоторых SAPI в PHP 5.3.0, и удалена в PHP-FPM в PHP 7.0.0.